# How to test a Spring REST consumer with JUnit

Tags: java, rest, junit, integration-testing

I'm creating a Java Spring based microservice application that communicates using REST endpoints.

The app itself is so far has a simple structure: UI <-> DBLayer. The UI module is a api consumer and DBLayer is an api provider.

That being said I would like to test if my UI makes the **correct** REST calls using JUnit and/or Mockito. To be more specific, say I have a service class like this:

```
@Service
public class AuthorityService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Authority getAuthority(String authorityName) {
        Authority authority = 
               restTemplate.getForObject(
                  "http://localhost:8080/authorities/" + authorityName,
                   Authority.class);           
        return authority;
    }
}
```

In order to test this service method I would like to somehow verify that exactly this endpoint was called. Is there a way to wrap the service method and somehow assert a rest GET/POST/PUT etc. calls being made?

The desired test class should look something like this:

```
public class AuthorityServiceTest {
    private AuthorityService authorityService = new AuthorityService();

    @Test
    public void getAuthorityTest(){
        Assert.assertHttpGETCallMade(
                authorityService.getAuthority("test"),
                "http://localhost:8080/authorities/test");
    }
}
```

Comment: @npinti if I understand you correctly that would ensure that the REST call reaches the api, however I would like to just check that the call is being made. This way the tests won't fail even though the server is down/under development. 
In other words I would like to create a sort of contract test for the UI, thus making the tests decoupled from the server (provider) side.

Comment: I see your point. Removing my comment.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the testing tutorial section provided by Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/. Besides that you can verify with Mockito that the method is called with the `verify` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Mockito to inject the template, then verify the call.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) // RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) for JUnit 4
public class AuthorityServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private AuthorityService sut;

    @Mock RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void getAuthorityTest(){
        // mock rest call
        Authority auth = mock(Authority.class);
        when(restTemplate.getForObject(any(String.class), any(Class.class)).thenReturn(auth);

        Authority result = sut.getAuthority("test");

        // verify mock result was returned
        assertSame(auth, result);
        // verify call to rest template was performed
        verify(restTemplate).getForObject(
              "http://localhost:8080/authorities/test",
               Authority.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using Mockito to test the Web Layer versus the test library of Spring self (see: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)? I agree with verifying that the method is called with Mockito is correct. However in my opinion it's better to use the Spring test library in the case of testing web calls.

Comment: @RemcoBuddelmeijer The test I posted is a unit test; it tests the service and the service alone. The Spring test starts up the Spring context, so it tests more than just this service, but the whole concertation of beans within the application. This means that a) it can fail for other reasons and b) it can take considerable time to run. You should have both kinds of tests in your overall setup, but they verify different things.